# how to access data class values from the context of the main method

Tags: android, kotlin

in the below code, i created the below posted data classes. however when i tried to access this classes from the context of the main method.

i could not query parameter and consequently the search info and etc.

please let me know how to fix this issue

**code**:

```
// Kotlin Hello World Program
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
println("Hello, World!")

ObjectModel.ResultOfQuery.
}
```

**data classes**

```
public class ObjectModel {

    data class ResultOfQuery(val query: Query)
    data class Query(val searchinfo: SearchInfo)
    data class SearchInfo(val totalhits: Int)
}
```

Comment: u have to create this object then u will get access to it val resultOfQuery = ResultOfQuery(query)

Answer (score 1):

```
data class User(
  val name : String,
  val surname : String = "",
  val age : Int = 0
)
User("Steve")
User("Steve", "Jobs")
User("Steve", "Jobs", 56)
User("Steve",56) // This wont compile
```

In Your case, You may need to use

```
ObjectModel().ResultOfQuery(query)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sealed class ObjectModel {

data class ResultOfQuery(val query: Query)
data class Query(val searchinfo: SearchInfo)
data class SearchInfo(val totalhits: Int)
}
```

Sealed class might be what you need to use
https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/sealed-classes.html